# How would one implement class weighting for individual federated learning clients?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am attempting to utilise TensorFlow Federated for an image classification task with 7 classes and 3-5 clients. Each client has a different class distribution of labels. I have successfully implemented [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) for my use-case and am now looking for improvements. I have a few questions:

1. Can individual clients have different class weights in their loss function based on the class distribution that is unique to that client?
2. If so, how would one implement this?
3. If not, is it because federated averaging process requires that the clients and the global model share the same loss function?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, I can say yes, individual clients can have different class weight, in this case we talk about non iid data . Suppose that we have 7 labels, each client have data from 1 or 2 labels.